# sum 2 case functions while joining 3 tables sql sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I am trying to SUM two CASE functions (2 columns **PotentialOrderGain** and **PotentialFreightLoss** from case statements) that I just created in my query. I need to create a new column as **NetGainLoss** by summing these 2 case functions together. I know i can use cte method to do that. But at the same time, I need to inner join 3 tables together. The 3 tables are **Person.Address** and **Sales.SalesOrderHeader** and **Sales.vIndividualCustomer**. I don't know how to achieve all of them in a big query. Below please find my query. Many thanks in advance!

```
select h.SalesOrderID,
       i.StateProvinceName as ShipToState,
       h.OrderDate,
       h.SubTotal,
       h.Freight,
       case when h.SubTotal>=1500 and h.SubTotal<2000 then 2000-h.SubTotal
       when h.SubTotal<1500 then 0
       when h.SubTotal>=2000 then 0
       end as PotentialOrderGain,
       case when h.SubTotal>=1500 and h.SubTotal<2000 then 0.22-h.Freight
       when h.SubTotal<1500 then 0
       when h.SubTotal>=2000 then 0.22-h.Freight
       end as PotentialFreightLoss
from Sales.vIndividualCustomer i
inner join Person.Address a
on a.City = i.City
inner join Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
on a.AddressID = h.ShipToAddressID
where i.StateProvinceName='California'
order by h.SalesOrderID;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a slow/inefficient method because of the large amount of data brought into the fourth join but it should give you a starting point:

```
select 
    h.SalesOrderID
    ,i.StateProvinceName as ShipToState
    ,h.OrderDate
    ,h.SubTotal
    ,h.Freight
    ,SumTotals.PotentialOrderGain + SumTotals.PotentialFreightLoss as NetGainLoss
    from Sales.vIndividualCustomer i
    inner join Person.Address a on a.City = i.City
    inner join Sales.SalesOrderHeader h on a.AddressID = h.ShipToAddressID
    inner join (SELECT  ShipToAddressID,      
            case when h.SubTotal>=1500 and h.SubTotal<2000 then 2000-h.SubTotal
            when h.SubTotal<1500 then 0
            when h.SubTotal>=2000 then 0
            end as PotentialOrderGain,
            case when h.SubTotal>=1500 and h.SubTotal<2000 then 0.22-h.Freight
            when h.SubTotal<1500 then 0
            when h.SubTotal>=2000 then 0.22-h.Freight
            end as PotentialFreightLoss
            FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
            )SumTotals ON a.AddressID = SumTotals.ShipToAddressID
where i.StateProvinceName='California'
order by h.SalesOrderID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select h.SalesOrderID,
i.StateProvinceName as ShipToState,
h.OrderDate,
h.SubTotal,
h.Freight,
SUM
(case when h.SubTotal>=1500 and h.SubTotal<2000 then 2000-h.SubTotal
when h.SubTotal<1500 then 0
when h.SubTotal>=2000 then 0
end)
-
(case when h.SubTotal>=1500 and h.SubTotal<2000 then 0.22-h.Freight
when h.SubTotal<1500 then 0
when h.SubTotal>=2000 then 0.22-h.Freight
end)
as NetFreightLoss
from Sales.vIndividualCustomer i
inner join Person.Address a
on a.City = i.City
inner join Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
on a.AddressID = h.ShipToAddressID
where i.StateProvinceName='California'
group by
h.SalesOrderID,
i.StateProvinceName as ShipToState,
h.OrderDate,
h.SubTotal,
h.Freight
order by h.SalesOrderID;
```